# How to handle cyclic dependencies

Tags: c++, dependencies, dependency-management, circular-dependency

I'm having some trouble with cyclic dependencies. Imagine the following sample classes:

A class A with instance variables of types C and D and a method that uses these 2 types inside plus another type D:

```
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"
#include "D.h"

class A {

private:
    B b;
    C c;

    void foo(D d);
};
```

A class B that depends on C:

```
#include "C.h"

class C;

class B {

private:
    C c;

    //some methods
};
```

A class C that uses methods of class D:

```
#include "D.h"

class D;

class C {

private:
    double x;

    void bar(D d);
};
```

A class D that has methods that use variables of the type B and C:

```
#include "B.h"
#include "C.h"

class B;
class C;

class D {

private:
    int i;

    void foo2(B b);
    void bar2(C c);
};
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
B.h:8:2 error: ‘C’ does not name a type
```

How can I solve this problem with cyclic dependencies?

Thanks

Edit:
Updated class B:

```
#include "C.h"

class C;

class B {

private:
    C* c;

    B (B b) {*c = *(b.c);} //copy constructor
    //some methods
};
```

Comment: If you need a variable of an incomplete type it needs to be a reference or a pointer.

Comment: Don't `#include` what you don't need. Parameters and return values do not need the definition of a type, only its declaration.

Comment: With correct forward declaration: https://ideone.com/GlaaWT

Comment: The tricky part is that you take argument by value. but the argument can even be forward declared; argument definition should be known at call site (and probably also for the function definition).

Comment: @Jarod42 I tried that and I still get the same error

Comment: @fc67: I provided an ideone link which works with one unique file (with comment to split in different files)

Comment: @NathanOliver I changed the variable C c in the class B to C* c and C& c and on both I get the same error because there are some operators from class C that I need to use

Comment: @fc67 then re edit your post with the code as it is now and the errors you are getting

Comment: @NathanOliver I edited the post with the updated code